# How to normalize 4D array ( not an image)?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, normalization

I have a 4D array of shape `(1948, 60, 2, 3)` which tells the difference in end effector positions (x,y,z) over 60 time steps.
The number `1948` indicates the number of samples, `60` is the number of time steps, `2` is for left_arm and right_arm, `3` denotes the x,y,z positions.

a sample of how it looks is below:

```
array([[[  3.93048840e-05,   7.70215296e-04,   1.13865805e-03],
        [  1.11679799e-04,  -7.04810066e-04,   1.83552688e-04]],

   [[ -6.26468389e-04,   6.86668923e-04,   1.57112482e-04],
    [  3.68164582e-04,   7.98948528e-04,   4.50642200e-04]],

   [[  2.51472961e-04,  -2.48105983e-04,   7.52486843e-04],
    [  8.99905240e-05,   1.70473461e-04,  -3.09927572e-04]],

   [[ -7.52414330e-04,   5.46782063e-04,  -3.76679264e-04],
    [ -3.12531026e-04,  -3.36585211e-04,   5.79075595e-05]],

   [[  7.69968002e-04,  -1.95524291e-03,  -8.65666619e-04],
    [  2.37583215e-04,   4.59415986e-04,   6.07292643e-04]],

   [[  1.41795261e-03,  -1.62364401e-03,  -8.99673829e-04],
```

I want to normalize this data  as I need tot rain on a neural netowrk. How do I go about normalizing a 4D array I have an intuition for images. Can I normalize each example data or should the normalization be there for the entire 4D array?

Comment: Which normalizing formula are you using?

Comment: There are different approaches. You can normalize each individual example or do batch-norm

Comment: For images, I would use (x - x_min)/ (x_max - x_min)

Comment: @Maxim I see, so you are saying I can run normalization for 1948 times, normalizing data with respoect to every example? But, I kind of don't understand how is that centering the data. Every example can have it's own min and max value right?

Comment: OK, I've seen cases when batch-norm is not applicable. But, in general, you can do it for the whole training data. Is your question: can/should you do that or not?

Comment: So, that would be normalization per x,y,z?

Comment: @Divakar I am trying to normalize across (x,y,z). 
I am just stuck accessing the indices. I create `b = np.random.randint(100,size=(4,2,3,5))`, but I am not getting right output to access all the samples across all batches for the feature x.

Comment: So, `x_min` would be of shape (4,2,3) or would it be (5)?

Comment: @Divakar shouldn't x_min be a single value as I am trying to get the minimum, of first column for for all row,time_steps,batches.
Batch size is 4, time steps is 2, row per time step is 3 and total column number is 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick would be to use `keepdims` set as `True`, which lets the broadcasting happen without bothering us with the housekeeping work of extending dims. Hence, the solution for generic ndarrays that would handle generic dimension arrays would be -

```
# Get min, max value aming all elements for each column
x_min = np.min(x, axis=tuple(range(x.ndim-1)), keepdims=1)
x_max = np.max(x, axis=tuple(range(x.ndim-1)), keepdims=1)

# Normalize with those min, max values leveraging broadcasting
out = (x - x_min)/ (x_max - x_min)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps! But in general, I am not able to access the elements and getting super confused. `b[:,:,:,0]` is not giving the output of  entire first column where `b = np.random.randint(100,size=(4,2,3,5))`

How can I access the first column x across the dataset

Comment: @deeplearning `b[:,:,:,0]` is the first column. So, `b[:,:,:,0].min()` and `b[:,:,:,0].max()` would be the min, max values. We are getting those for all the columns with `x_min` and `x_max` as shown in the post. Aren't those what you would use for the normalization?

Comment: You're right, I got the output, I see how 'keep_dims' helps. But, what does  `axis=tuple(range(x.ndim-1))` do ? hwere the axis = (0,1,2) what axis does this represent?

Answer (score 0):

First, yes you can do normalization and there is no problem with that.

Second, there is nothing special about 4D arrays. Normalization simply should be performed separately for each feature. Thus depending on the type of the normalization, you should calculate the max and min (or mean and std) values for each feature across all samples in the training set.

In your case you should decide which parts of the data refer to the same distribution. So decide on each dimension:

1) First dimension is just number of samples, so it doesn't make new distribution. Treat it as number of data entries.

2) Time step. Here you should decide: does x,y,z values have unique distribution at each of 60 timesteps? If no, treat it the same way as previous step. If yes, calculate max,min (or mean, std) for following feature, separately for each time step. (For simplicity, think like does arm at step 0 can actually have similar values to 30, 60? If yes again they all correspond to data entries, no: x60 features)

3) Do left arm and right arm have different x,y,z values? If yes, again calculate them separately. ( I guess they do, because left and right arm statistically tend to occupy different points in space)

4) x,y,z values definitely independent distributions, so calculate them separately.

Now when you decide you will have features between 3 and 360 (depending on your decisions) so calculate necessary values for them (max, min or mean, std) and perform standard routine.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! My timesteps do not make a new distribution, hence I need to normalize it only across (x,y,z). 
I am just stuck accessing the indices. I create `b = np.random.randint(100,size=(4,2,3,5))`, but I am not getting right output to access all the samples across all samples in the batch for the feature x.

Comment: @deeplearning you can make it with numpy, for example, means = np.mean(b,(0,1)), stds = np.std(b,(0,1)), as a result you will get means and std of shapes [2,3] corresponding to each of the features required. In brackets you basically indicate dimension to collapse or along which axises to find means/stds in other words.

Comment: @asakryukin At least leave a constructive comment with the downvote. Would have loved some feedback.

Comment: Think you should try to improve your solution by proposing some solution rather than simply throwing theories around.